# only show menu item after it's been hovered on for a period of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list item that when hovered upon slides down another inner list. Problem I'm having is if you quickly hover over it accidentally it slides down and some times even ends up in a weird loop where it bounces between closed and open. My solution is to set a slight delay before showing it.

```
 $('#overlayNav li').hover(
     function() {
         var that = this;
         setTimeout(function(){test(that)},1000);
         function test(param) {
             if(param.id) {
                 $(param).find('ul').slideDown({easing: "easeOutBounce", duration: 900});
             }
         },
```

Problem is all this code does it delay the slide. The hover is still detected even if you hover for a fraction of a second as before...the only difference is that there's now a delay before it shows...what I need to say is after the timeout if the mouse is still over that element then show it. How do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is keep track of the timer (via the element's `data`), and clear it on hover out:

```
$('#overlayNav li').hover(
     function() {
         var that = this;

         /*** Here! ***/
         $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function(){test(that)},1000));

         function test(param) {
             if(param.id) {
                 $(param).find('ul').slideDown({
                     easing: "easeOutBounce", duration: 900
                 });
             }
         }
     },
     function () {

         /*** And here! ***/
         var timer = $(this).data('timer');
         if (timer) $(this).data('timer', clearTimeout(timer));

     }
});
```

Comment: Ah I used the method you originally posted...using the classes - don't know why I didn't think of it! This is great as well though. thanks

Comment: @elduderino, the reason I switched to using `.data()` is because unless you `clearTimeout` the timeout will trigger in less than 1 second if you hover, leave, then hover again very quickly. Then again, that may not be so bad ;)

Comment: Oh yeah so it does - I quite like that - It's a feature!

Answer (score 3):

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Simply put, the best solution...:)

Comment: ok if you stick with < jQuery 1.4.2, otherwise Ben Alman's doTimeout plugin is a good alternative: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/ ... though not such an elegant implementation as Cherne's ... still waiting for the hoverIntent r6 release :)

Comment: Yeah I was looking for this as I've used it before but couldn't remember the name. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! glad to be of service